# How can I console log the results of my api search

Tags: angular, search, bootstrap-4, pipe, typeahead

I am following the example provided by angular using typeahead - found here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

I would like to see what is returned in the response but Im not sure how to console it out.

I have tried putting the console.log inside the pipe, and tried in the map but it is not a correct way to do it. I am not very familiar with pipes and maps so any help is appreciated.

In the code below I would like to know what is the response coming from the wiki api and then how it is returned to the search function.

```
/// this is where i want to know what is being returned.
return this.http
      .get(WIKI_URL, {params: PARAMS.set('search', term)}).pipe(
        map(response => response[1])
      );

// Where does this receive the above response and how is it doing the typeahead.

search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => this.searching = true),
      switchMap(term =>
        this._service.search(term).pipe(
          tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
          catchError(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return of([]);
          }))
      ),
      tap(() => this.searching = false)
    )
```

If I search "ja" in the search box it will provide a drop down all results starting with "ja" which is correct and what I eventually want to implement, but need to know what to return in order to do this.

I hope this makes sense. ANY help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `this.http.get(WIKI_URL, {params: PARAMS.set('search', term)}).pipe(
        map(response => response[1])
      ).subscribe(res => console.log(res));`

Comment: I normally write `console.log` inside a tap operator. Since they are mainly used for side effects

Comment: @C_Ogoo How would i do that?

would it be in this line:

tap(() => this.searchFailed = false)

Comment: yes, so it would be `tap((searchResults) => { console.log(searchResults); this.searchFailed = false })